# duplicate entry insert in database when using json_encode method in php

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, json

I am having problem in php mysql,get similar entry in database after calling json_encode method. This is my php code:

```
class xyz
{

    private $_mysqli;

    public function __construct( $hostname, $user, $password, $database ) {

        $this->_mysqli = new mysqli( $hostname, $user, $password, $database );
        if (  mysqli_connect_errno() ) {

            die('couldn\'t connect connection ('. mysqli_connect_errno(). ')'. mysqli_connect_error() );
        }

        return $this->_mysqli;

    }


    public function insert( $user, $app ) {

        if ($stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `track` ( user, app ) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

            $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $user, $app );

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();

        } else {

            printf( "Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $this->_mysqli->error );
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {

        return $this->_mysqli->close();

    }


    public function app( $params = array(), $index = NULL ) {

        //get ads from array based on scheduling

        if (is_null( $index )) {

            return $params;

        } else {

            //$this->insert( $user, $ap );

            echo json_encode(array('delay' => '43200000', 'success' => 'true', 'result' => json_encode($params[$index]) ));


        }
    }

}

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );

$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$app = $_REQUEST['app'];

require 'config.inc.php'; //file contain db credentials and array named $params

$res = new xyz( 'localhost', 'root' , '#####' ,'user_db' );

$res->insert( $user, $app );
$res->app($params, 1);
```

If i called `$res->insert_query( $imei, $pn )` and `$res->app($params, 1)`, it shows me json on browser one time but insert entry in database twice time. This happens in both cases, either i can put insert function in app function or called outside using class object. It was like there is a mistake in these function by me. But i can't resolve it, pl help me on this issue.

Comment: i see only `insert` method in your class not `insert_query`

Comment: Where is your insert_query method?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ : I apology for my typo mistake there is insert method instead of insert_query

Comment: You're either chopping your code too much, or picking wrong pieces. From what you post, `function app()` has nothing to do with database operation; it even doesn't make use of any resource associated with the object.

Comment: @Passerby: as you can see, i called first insert function and then app function which echo an json encoded array, if i put a simple echo in app function then insertion only once, but when using json encode entries get twiced in database

Comment: @shihon The thing is, in your posted code, `app()` method practically runs independently -- it never make use of any resource associated with the object; All it does is return a JSON built from whatever you give, so there's no way it will affect database operation. If there's any typo/missing part, update your question so others can see and help accordingly.

Comment: I didn't found any bug, in this case if i put database call method in different class then call both class for insert data and echo json, i am still getting duplicate entry

Comment: Then the problem does not lie on the part you posted. Try to use `var_dump` or `print_r` in a "step-by-step" manner and see if you can find something unexpected.

Comment: @Passerby: if i put an echo in insert function then it insert only once, even i also checked class flow through print constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since i am running ubuntu 11.10, and using chromium for browsing which have **critical bugs**. After spending some hours on this problem, i found there is a fight in **chromium browser** which throw another mysql insert query when using **json_encode** method of php, i also upgrade php package from 5.3.6 to 5.4 but still problem persist with chromium. On other hand, other browsers chrome, mozilla firefox, safari behaves normally and insert only a single entry with json_encode function. Also there is a no dynamically updates for chromium then it is pathetic for us to use it for development work.